# Twitter Bootstrap: Misplaced Column in Row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web, alignment

I just began using Bootstrap and am trying to write something with it.

So far it worked out great, but only one problem I cannot solve after 3 hours or trying.

I am trying to build a login page where the username text field and the password input field is on the same row, I separated them into 2 vertical column to help aligning elements, but somehow the two vertical column cannot be in the same row, even they are placed under the same `.row`

Screenshot here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jB8cd.png

Excuse me for insufficient reputation to post image...sorry for the trouble

Here is the related HTML code:

```
        <!-- Login Form and Button -->
        <div class="container-fluid" id = 'login'>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class= 'col-md-3 col-md-offset-3 login-form'>
                    <div>
                        <h4><strong>Login</strong></h4> 
                        <input class = 'textinput' type="text" placeholder='User Name'>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class ='col-md-3 col-md-offset-6 login-form login-right'  >
                    <div col id='remember'>
                        <input type='checkbox' name = 'remember-me'value = 'Remember'><em style='color:white;'>Remember me</em>
                    </div>
                    <input class = 'textinput' type="password" placeholder='Password'>
                    <br><br>
                    <div id = 'login-button' class = 'pull-right'>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        <!-- Login Button -->
        </div> <!-- Close Login Form-->
```

And the related CSS code:

```
.textinput{
    width: 100%;
    height: 2em;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.btn-default {
    width: 6em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    background-color: #67462f;
    border-color: #67462f;
}
```

------------------------------TL;DR-------------------------------

I put two `col-md-3` div in a row but they are not displaying inline, please tell me what I should do to make them displayed correctly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The offset in your second `div` is not necessary:

```
<div class='col-md-3 login-form login-right'>
```

Check [this bootply](http://www.bootply.com/cFEb8wR99b).

Answer (score 0):

```
col-md-3 col-md-offset-6
```

These are conflicting. You do one or the other. Realistically if they should line up together it would be two values equal (col-md-6) with the parent defining the container width.

Answer (score 0):

`<div class ='col-md-3 col-md-offset-6 login-form login-right'  >` should be 
`<div class ='col-md-3 col-md-offset-3 login-form login-right'  >` because this div and div before are added in single row, and when you have col-md-offset-6 this is offset 6 from the previous div where you have input for username.